# Mootools DatePicker manually type input

Tags: input, datepicker, mootools

Can a standard DatePicker be extended to allow you to manually type the input date ?
It does not matter if the panel shows up.

If so, any hints ?

The blockKeydown option did not work, nor the ( perhaps obsolete ) debug.

Comment: The `blockKeydown` option should work, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjaMc/).

Answer (score 2):

Use Option: `blockKeydown: false;`

```
blockKeydown: (*boolean*, defaults to true) 
    Whether it should block keydown events, 
    so the user can type into the input field or not.
```

Source: https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/#options-2